# Using ImageButton in Android Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, imageview

I'm trying to use the `ImageButton` in Eclipse IDE (ADT).

The IDE shows no errors at the time of compiling but when I run it in emulator it never starts instead it shows like UNFORTUNATELY YOUR APP HAS STOPPED WORKING.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

AND main.activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output

Comment: post your layout xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Change `Button` to `ImageView`
And in the xml add this line to your image view

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you cast an `ImageView` to a `Button`, which is incorrect.

Your variable `button1` must be of type `ImageView`.

You can also use the `ImageButton` type, but be sure to use compatible types in the XML layout and in your Java code.